# Refresh dropdownlist in angular without reloading the page

Tags: angularjs, angular, ajax, mean

I have a dropdown list(ng-multiselect-dropdown) of movies coming from database
i have a button to add new movie.
after adding a new movie, i want the list of movies to reload to fetch newly added movie without refreshing the whole page.

any suggestion?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For this, on button click. Just add push the movie to the array of movies with all the information. Else if you want to make the API calls, after API response, update the array.

Will this help?

Comment: i want to make an api call. I am updating the array. but as the page is already loaded dropdown list will not re-read the array. So what i think is i need to reload the dropdown list on the button click

Comment: Once the API is complete (to save the newly added movie), if the API returns the details of all movie, you can update the movie list from that. Or on success, you can instantiate another API to get all the list of movies again. Else directly update the list, if you already have all the details

Comment: after successful insert of new movie i am making another api call to fetch new movies. As my dropdown is already loaded on the page it will not take data from the new array because the drop is already initialised with old list. So i want dropdown list to reload the data from new array. I hope this is clear